# when i release my apps flutter application this happens in android studio

Tags: flutter, dart

```
C:\Users\i\Desktop\New folder\Covid-19-Flutter-UI-master>flutter build apk --release
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64,
android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or
split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:
        https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\i\Desktop\New folder\Covid-19-Flutter-UI-master\android\app\build.grad
le' line: 50

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\i\Desktop\New folder\Covid-19-Flutter-UI-master\andr
oid\app\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\i\Desktop\New folder\Covid-19-Flutter-UI-master\android\app\build.gr
adle': 50: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 50, column 15.
             "    }
                   ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to g
et more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

C:\Users\i\Desktop\New folder\Covid-19-Flutter-UI-master>
```

Comment: Add android\app\build.gradle file and also check there is no space build.gr adle.

Comment: An error dump is not a good question. Please [edit] and add context, preferably a [mcve]. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Follow all these steps: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Flutter and Android also recommend using App bundle as preferred over APK, so try using `flutter build appbundle` once you have followed all the steps.